# How to make a user role expire after 1 year?

Tags: 8, commerce, rules

I'm looking for a way to make a user role expire after 1 year. In Drupal 7 there is the [Role Expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_expire) module. I found [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1228560) using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. But I can't seem to figure out how to do this in Drupal 8.

More specific, what I want is for a user to buy a [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) product when payed, the user gets a user role to read articles behind a paywall. This role should be active for a year.

The only option I found is building a custom module but I want to try and find an other to do this first. Hope someone can help with a good suggestion or a push in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the following ways to do this:

1.As same as role expire another module User expire is available [User Expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_expire.).

2.By using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module you can expire the role after 1 Year.

Try these Modules hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. Before posting my question I already tried both modules. Via User Expire I have to set the date of expiring manually, and I want it to be automated when I commerce order is payed. With Rules  I can't figure out how to expire a role. See my original question and the post I found about rules in drupal 7. I can't seem to find the same functionality in the Drupal 8 variant of Rules. Could you help me a bit more with how to...in these two modules?

Answer (score 1):

Module [Role expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_expire) has now a working version for Drupal 8.